# x-editable process response of remote source

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I am populating checklist using remote source. My problem is that the remote source returns 
`{count: n, results: {...}}`, and x-editable doesnt expect to have to look in `response.results` to get the list.

I have tried the following, which does not solve:

```
       $ages.editable({
            type: 'checklist',
            source: '/api/ages/',
            sourceOptions: {
                success: function(resp){
                    return resp.results;
                }
            }
        })
```

Using console, I can see that `.success` is being hit, but the behaviour on screen is the "loading" spinner keeps on spinning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.ajax` has `dataFilter` callback, which passes return value to `success`. Note `dataFilter` must return `JSON`, so below works:

```
dataFilter: function(resp){
    return JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(resp).results);
}
```